# Split directories in git to new repository

Tags: git, repository, git-remote, git-filter-branch

I dont know if my approach is correct but I get the result as I want.
Could you help me figure out?

I have a repository abbr repo with 3 solutions which I split up.

Before:

```
Root
|_Project1
|_Project2
|_Project3
```

After:

```
Root
|_Project1
```

etc etc.

My approach:

```
git clone <url-to-old-repo> <new-repo-folder>
cd <new-repo-folder>
git checkout <branch>
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch \
   --prune-empty \
   --index-filter '
      git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- \
      <project-folder>
   ' \
   -- \
   --all
git remote add origin <url-to-new-repo>
git push -u origin <branch>
```

After all these commands, I end up with a new repo with my folder I want and the history is preserved. And this is done with all 3 projects. The remaining repo which contains all project is unused in future, maybe kept for backup.

Comment: see also 'git help subtree'.

Comment: I have read about it and it does not fulfill my goal.